# Return derived type when return type is base type c#

Tags: c#-4.0, generics, interface, abstract-class, derived-class

I have a Base abstract Class and a Derived Class

Base abstract class

```
public abstract class BaseData: IListingData
    {
        private int? _photos;
        public string DataKey { get; set; }
        public abstract List<Images> Photos { get; set; }
}
```

Derived Class

```
public class DerivedData1 : BaseData
    {
        public override List<Images> Photos
        {
            get
            { return new List<Images>(); } set {}
        }
     }

public class DerivedData2 : BaseData
        {
            public override List<Images> Photos
            {
                get
                { return new List<Images>(); } set {}
            }
         }
```

I have a Service function:

```
 public List<ListingData> FilterListings(PredicateHandler predicates)
        {
            //Retrieved from database and based on certain predicates, it will create List of DerivedData1 or DerivedData2

            Return new List<DerivedData1>(); //This is where the ERROR is.
         }
```

I am unable to return Derived Type. I tried casting and I get the following same compile error. *Cannot convert expression type 'System.Collections.Generic.List< DerivedData1>' to return type 'System.Collections.Generic.List< ListingData>'*

I also tried changing the return type of the service function *FilterListings()* to the Interface *IListingData*, but I still encounter the a casting error.

I searched on other Stackoverflow posts. Which answers the questions of returning a derived Type from within a Base class. But I think this is a different scenario.

Bottom line, My service-class function has a return type *Animal()* and from inside the function I want to return *Dog()*

What am I missing?

Comment: Read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd799517%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In your example code, you cannot return new List of DerivedData1 where the function return type is List of ListingData.
The reason is there is no hierarchical relations between the two list types.
What you can do is:

```cs
 public List<ListingData> FilterListings(PredicateHandler predicates)
        {
            var list = new List<BaseData>();
            var list.Add(new DerivedData1());
            var list.Add(new DerivedData2());

            return list;
         }
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd use `List<object>` if I were in your place, and cast `object` to whatever is needed when iterating (for example). Your issue is that `List<Base>` and `List<DerivedFromBase>` are treated as unrelated (which is the intended behaviour, even if uncomfortable).